# Про props img react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как через Props добавить изображения? Обучение в React JS

```
const Service = (props) =>  {
  return (
    <div className="service">
      <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      <p>{props.age}</p>
      <a> {props.img} </a>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Service name="User Research" age="14" 
         />
      <Service name="IA And Wireframes" age="14"/>
      <Service name="User Testing" age="14"/>
      <Service name="Looks and Feel
Design (UI)" age="14"/>
      <Service name="Delivery" age="14"/>
      <Service name="Integration Support" age="14"/>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Эмммм в какой в смысле вызвать ?

Comment: Ну имена, возраст и прочее вызываем же..

Comment: Это не вызов.С начало выучите сам реакт и что такое пропсы

Comment: Ну пусть не вызов, но как добавить изображения также как name?

Comment: У вас что-то с терминологией не то, поскольку это вызов компонента Service, внутри которого простое подставление значений в HTML код. Ну и обычный код HTML для изображений: `<a><img src={props.img} alt="img" /></a>`, при условии, что внутри `props.img` ссылка.